# build issue for cucumber cpp in windows and with visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, cucumber, cucumber-cpp

I am trying to setup an environment for cucumber cpp in windows 10 and with visual studio. While trying to build the whole solution, I am facing build issues with GTest component

My current environment is as  follow

> OS: Windows 10 
>   Visual Studio Community Edition 2017
>   CMake Version:3.14.3
>   Ruby Version: 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x64-mingw32]
>   Boost Library Version: 1.69.0

I followed the steps mentioned in Readme.md

Building Cucumber-Cpp with tests and samples:

```
# Download test suite
git submodule init
git submodule update

# Create build directory
cmake -E make_directory build

# Generate Makefiles
cmake -E chdir build cmake -DCUKE_ENABLE_EXAMPLES=on -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${prefix} ..

# Build cucumber-cpp and tests
cmake --build build

I am facing build issue with GTest component. Below is the error message

========================================================

Performing build step for 'gtest'
  CMake Error at C:/Cucumber/cucumber-cpp/build/gmock/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-build-Debug.cmake:49 (message):
    Command failed: 1


     'C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe' '--build' '.' '--config' 'Debug'


    See also


      C:/Cucumber/cucumber-cpp/build/gmock/src/gtest-stamp/gtest-build-*.log




C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(209,
5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [C:\Cucumber\cucumber-cpp\build\gtest.vcxproj]


========================================================
```

Comment: So what do the logs say?

Comment: Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.21+g9802d43bc3 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  gtest-all.cc
C:\Cucumber\cucumber-cpp\build\gmock\src\gtest\include\gtest/gtest-printers.h(497): error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated [C:\Cucumber\cucumber-cpp\build\gmock\src\gtest-build\gtest.vcxproj]

Comment: Thanks for the info. You should edit your question and add it there.